# Can you access a HTML form data from the event property, or a "this" keyword, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events, this

I know that you can easily get data from a form like:

```js
function getData(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      const inpt = document.getElementById("inpt").value;
        return inpt;
}

//OR

function getData(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      const inpt = document.getElementById('form').elements[0].value;
        return inpt;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="getData(event)">
      <input id="inpt" type="text"></input>
</form>
```

what I'd like to know is if this same value could be reached through the event property or a `this` keyword, withou using a "getElementBy..." of any sort or any querySelector.

Comment: Don't use `on*` attributes. Use `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Quentin like, always, or only for this specific case?

Comment: Always. They are more trouble then they are worth. They do stupid things with scope. They depend on global. They force you to move JS out of your JS files and into HTML attributes. Any remotely complex JS you put there needs HTML encoding. They do stupid things with scope (which is worth mentioning twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the event listener is set on the form, the form element is available as

`event.target`

And so the text field value would be accessible by

`event.target.elements[0].value`

The form element is also `this` within the submit handler, so you could also do

`this.elements[0].value`.

Comment: `getData` is called without anything being passed to the `event` argument, so your first two attempts will error because `event` is `undefined`.

Comment: Your third attempt will error because `this` is `window` and so `this.elements` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Quentin the argument thing was my mistake, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I like James' answer better. Much simpler. Haven't tested either too extensively sorry.

If you assign all of your form elements a name attribute, on the form submission event you can use the FormData Api to get their data. I believe this won't work on I.E. or other older browsers (check for browser compatibility).
Form Data: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#browser_compatibility
Object.fromEntries(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#browser_compatibility

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="getData()">
      <input name="input1" id="inpt" type="text"></input>
      <input name="input2" id="NotNeededForThis" type="text"></input>
</form>
```

```
function getData(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        const formObject = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
        return formObject;
}
```

This will return the object:

```
{
    input1: "whatever the value was",
    input2: "whatever the value was"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of the input through the event directly. For example in the function to access the data of the input field with the name 'input1':

```js
function getData(event){
     //format event.target.nameOfInput.value
     //for the input field with the name input1
     let inp1 = event.target.input1.value;
     //for the input field with the name input2
     let inp2 = event.target.input2.value;
     //
     console.log( inp1 , inp2)
}
```